# Problem with hibernate mapping (change anotations with xml)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-boot, mapping

I have a spring-hibernate application which work fine with JPA anotations, but I want to change anotations with xml configuration, but but I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [FROM User]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [FROM User]
```

User.java

```
package com.fp.models;

public class User implements UserDetails {

    private long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private Set<Role> authorities;

    public User() {
    }
```

User.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.fp.models.User" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="user_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username" type="string"/>
        <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/>
        <set name="authorities" table="users_roles"
             inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
            <key>
                <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.fp.models.Role">
                <column name="role_id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HibernateConfiguration.java ->  https://pastebin.com/DrcGSBAp
this is the configuration which i use with the anotations

Method for test:

```
@Override
    public int listAllUsers() {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            String hql = "FROM User";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            if (query.list().size() == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            System.out.println(he.getMessage());
            throw he;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most probably hibernate just didn't see your XML. Where did you put it? What's its location?
Also have you tried to explicitly add it to hibernate config like it is described here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap

Comment: In hibernate config file i have "sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.fp.models.XMLModels")" <- here are my .xml files